# How to allow login based in association in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm learning about CakePHP, and i want to allow the users to do login if your profile is made.

Currently i have two models `User` and `Profile`, in the Admin panel i create first User and after if the profile, but to protect my application i want to allow login if the profile is already made.

I've already tried verify in `beforeFilter()` but i need to do a query to verify, i think is not good.

Login code

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = null;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->errorAlert(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
    }

    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
        return $this->redirect('/panel');
    }
}
```

There is other way to verify it?

Comment: Just a note, if you're learning CakePHP and creating a new application, then you should definitely start with CakePHP 3! CakePHP 2 is old school, and IMHO really shouldn't be used for new projects anymore.

Comment: Thank you, i'll to take in consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like.

**For CakePHP 3.x: Check in `login()` function.**

After user login, CakePHP returns an array of `$user` object. You can use the `$user['id']` to check for records in the `Profile` model like

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = null;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($user) {
            // Check for profile record
            $profile = $this->Users->Profiles->find()
               ->where([
                   'Profiles.user_id' => $user['id']
               ])->first();

            if (!$profile) {
               $this->Flash->error(__('Your profile is not ready yet. Please try again later'));
               return somewhere;
            } else {
               $this->Auth->setUser($user);
               $this->Flash->success(__('Login success'));
               return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        }
        $this->Flash->errorAlert(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
    }
}
```

**For CakePHP 2.x: Check in login() function**

This example will work with CakePHP 2.x.

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = null;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $profile = $this->Profile->find('first', [
                     'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                  ]);

            if (!$profile) {
                $this->Flash->errorAlert(__('Your profile is not ready yet. Please try again later'));
            } else {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        }
        $this->Flash->errorAlert(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
    }

    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
        return $this->redirect('/panel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to AuthComponent::identify() must be an instance of CakeRequest, none given,

Comment: can you show your **AppController**? Also, are you using CakePHP 3 or CakePHP 2?

Comment: Cake2, i'll migrate later.

**AppController** https://pastebin.com/TitkSziA

Comment: Updated answer for CakePHP 2. Please check if it works for you.